# Workaround to change Batch class to use QueryLocator

Tags: managed-package, batch

In my haste to get a new batch class running I accidentally packaged it such that the `start()` method returns an iterable (`List<SObject>`) instead of a Query Locator. Bad developer, no Twinkie.

Annoyingly the interface is `global` so that it can be invoked via anonymous apex inside of client orgs, and yet a client's org has too many rows in the queried object to run (> 50k). It seems that I don't have an option to overload this: even trying to use `@deprecated` and adding a second `start()` method that leverages a Query Locator does not work.

I've contacted support to see if I can get the class removed from the package since this class is only in a single org anyway, but can anyone think of a good way around the problem short of adding a second class?

Comment: How about adding a virtual keyword so that you can overload ?I have not tried to batch start method but guessing at this point .

Comment: No go... "method already defined".

Comment: Is it an option to deprecate the current class and create a new one? Any approach will be painful at this point.

Comment: @LanceShi That's all I can think of, really want to keep it clean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can convince the "one org" to uninstall the package, Salesforce can roll back the package to a "beta" version, which will let you fix your mistake. Your client will be inconvenienced, though, because you'll have to export all the data, uninstall, reinstall, and reload all the data. It's not good. Otherwise, you'll have to go with a new class entirely. For the record, I'd personally recommend not using either of the documented return types in the future, and use `Iterable<Object>` instead. `Iterable<Object>` is implemented by `List<SObject>` (and all the specific types) as well as `Database.QueryLocator`. This gives you the flexibility to choose which you'd like to use later.

---

For some reason that's beyond me, `Database.QueryLocator` won't return as an `Iterable<Object>` unless you cast it, making the basic framework look like this:

```
global class BatchProcess implements 
    Database.Batchable<Object>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

    String query;

    global Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return (Iterable<Object>)Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Object[] scope) {
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: So you still get the 50 million row ability without locking in `QueryLocator` as the return type? Nice.

Comment: That's a pretty sneaky way of doing it! Definitely going to use that in the future.

Comment: @KeithC Yes, I found this technique in a quest to make a flexible exec anon batch class. You still get all your normal limits, but you can return lists of normal objects, a query locator, and even custom Iterable objects.

Comment: Can't remove the package and haven't found any way of tricking the checker through casts and the like so it looks as though I'm stuck with it. This is what happens when you have to package to try out new ideas in a client org :/

Comment: My colleague @StanK can't get a batchable where `Iterable<Object>` is the return type of `start` to compile in the current and earlier API versions and neither can I. What are we missing?

Comment: @KeithC the secret sauce is to cast to an `Iterable<Object>` for the return type. I've added an example for you. This class will copy-paste into an org verbatim for you to play with.

Comment: @StanK What if I told you that instanceOf was lying, and you simply had to convince the compiler that you meant what you said? Simply by casting the return type, the compiler will then allow you to return `Database.QueryLocator` as the return type, and the runtime will accept a `Database.QueryLocator` to generate the records that will be used for the batch.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the secret sauce from both Stan (who hasn't enough points to comment) and me! Stan tried it and all OK including for > 50,000 records.